# How to get hard tabs on stdout in Python

Tags: python, tabs, stdout

I want to paste the output of my Python script into a spreadsheet. For this to work, the output should use hard tabs, and not spaces, to separate fields. How to I convince Python that tabs is what I want?

```
print("a\tb")
```

does not do it, and neither does

```
print("a", "b", sep="\t")
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'd advise writing to a CSV file, and opening that with the spreadsheet program instead.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Sure, there are alternatives (but see my reply to SteinerLima below: overkill for my purpose and less flexible to boot as it would not allow me to paste in single lines) - still, apart from my particular use case, writing tabs seems something you might want to do. I was quite surprised to find out they get converted to whitespace by default

Comment: What program are you using to view the python output?  A terminal client like putty?

Comment: Just running from command line (xterm)

Comment: I agree that you might want to write tabs (+1 to this question from me), but writing to a CSV file seems like it would be the more flexible (and with Python, relatively easy) solution for this specific problem. It sounds like you might want to, for instance, save the output for later use.

Comment: I tried pasting the result of `print('a\tb')` into Excel, and it worked like a charm. Which spreadsheet application are you using?

Comment: OK, this is not a Python issue but an xterm issue... Sorry to have wasted your time. Now how do I close this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion of

```
print("a\tb")
```

will indeed output `a<TAB>b`.

Verify this yourself in Python Shell / IDLE, or by writing this `a\tb` string to file and opening it in any notepad-type program.

The problem likely arises in whatever you're using to view the output.  In my current PuTTY setup, tabs are "invisibly" translated to spaces.

EDIT: For xterm, see [this "bug" report](http://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2004/07/msg00665.html).